# How to make the TimePicker smaller

Tags: android, android-layout, datetimepicker

Is it possible to make the default TimePicker smaller in the activity xml? I have searched this but so far only found out how to create a custom time picker which I do not want to do, or create a popup window which I also don't want to have to do. Has anyone tried this with any success? My TimePicker is sitting in a tableRow in a scrollView. Cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot change the size of TimePicker, how ever you can do one thing. You can make TimePicker as a Dialog.

Checkout the following code:

```
Button setTime;
setTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
setTime.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    TimePickerDialog tp1 = new TimePickerDialog(this, this, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
    tp1.show();
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
{
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think thats what ill have to end up doing. I have done the same for a date picker so I will probably make it the same. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hi there, I do not think this is the answer to the question but it seems the best solution so far as I have not found another way to do this. Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually, this is an ideal practice. Android OS adheres to this method.

Answer (score 22):

You can do this. I had also same problem. But Google helped me.
You have to just change your XML file.

```
android:scaleY="0.90" & android:scaleX="0.90"
```

It will small your picker with percentage value which you provide.

Works only from API 11.

Comment: Works only form API 11

Comment: The widget still occupies the same space... :/