# Reduce TimePicker size

Tags: android, datapicker

I want to create an app but the Time Picker is too big. I want to make it smaller and have tried resizing it but when I do it I cuts a portion of the time picker, is there a way to make it smaller?

Comment: are you using the time picker from an xml?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837581/how-to-make-the-timepicker-smaller/26970634#26970634

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android allows the user to pick date and time as ready to use dialogs.. you will not require to include the picker in the XML

Check this [Android Pickers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

Hope it helps you

Comment: well im creating it in the XML , true but im new to android so i dont know how to work will this advanced stuff, but i will keep reading it, thanks.

Comment: just follow the example given in the above link.. its straight forward

Comment: if u find the example useful please mark the answer as accepted.. both will get reputation points and will help others who look at your post.-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with weight sum inside a restricted container (such as by the screen size or forced padding).
I've posted in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33702510/2584698) how did it work for me.