# Is it possible to scale a TimePickerDialog (or a Dialog)?

Tags: android, resize, scale, android-dialog, android-timepicker

I have a simple/default `TimePickerDialog`:

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity());
timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
timePickerDialog.show();
```

**My problem:**

No matter how the device dimension (4", 7", 10"...) , the dialog always take the full screen size when it's shown (screenshot below).

[image]

**My question:**

Is it possible to **scale** (not resize) the dialog view?

Like this:

[image]

**PS**:

1) I don't want to use a Dialog with a custom view.

2) This is what i get when i resize the  dialog:

```
 Display display =((WindowManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
 int width = display.getWidth();
 int height=display.getHeight();

 timePickerDialog.getWindow().setLayout((width) / 2, (height) / 2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create your own time picker dialog by extending it.

read the following thread.

[Show TimePicker with minutes intervals in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214547/show-timepicker-with-minutes-intervals-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how to scale my custom dialog?

Comment: I created my own custom dialog picker by using own UI. and then set the values and validations.

Comment: Ok, i see. But i don't want to use a custom/own view.

Comment: You can scale down the dialog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837581/how-to-make-the-timepicker-smaller

Comment: I've tried those answers: The first one is not really an answer because he just use a simple TimePickerDialog, so there is no scale. The second one requires using a custom view and scale the view (or TimePicker) from xml.

Comment: create a dialog and show a timepicker inside the dialog.its the best thing you can do

Comment: Other wise use a scroller.